# Working with DOM after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function:

```
$('body').on('click', '.kategorija_izbor ul a, .mali_oglas a[role=pretraga]', function(e){
        var mgl_wrapper = $('.mali_oglasi_wrapper'),
        mgl = $(".mali_oglasi"), 
        mgl_space =  $(this).attr('href').replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
        link = mgl_space + ' .mali_oglasi';         
        mgl.animate({'opacity' : 0}, 400, function(){
            mgl_wrapper.load(link, function(){
                mgl.animate({'opacity' : 1}, 400);
            });
        });
        e.preventDefault(); 
    });
```

It is working, but I would like to know is there another way to do it. It seems to me that this way is time consuming and resource inefficient. Every time page is clicked script is going through DOM and search for specific elements. Is there a way to store **.kategorija_izbor ul a** and  .mali_oglas a[role=pretraga] (they are bout loaded via load function )?

**EDIT I**

**.kategorija_izbor ul a** and  .mali_oglas a[role=pretraga] are children of **mgl_wrapper *( $('.mali_oglasi_wrapper'))**, and they are dynamically created every time they are clicked.

Comment: You should post it on jsFiddle to get the definite answer, because it totally depends on when and how many times the elements are loaded with AJAX. If you can give more details I'm sure it can be optimized

Comment: have you try this. $('.kategorija_izbor ul a, .mali_oglas a[role=pretraga]').on('click', your Function here (){});

Comment: @naugtur I have added an explanation.

Answer (score 4):

If the elements are only being loaded into `mgl`, just restrict the `click` handler's scope so jQuery doesn't have to search through the entire `body`:

```
var $mgl_wrapper = $('.mali_oglasi_wrapper');
var $mgl = $('.mali_oglasi');

$mgl.on('click', '.kategorija_izbor ul a, .mali_oglas a[role=pretraga]', function(e) {
    var mgl_space =  this.href.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();

    $mgl.animate({'opacity' : 0}, 400, function() {
        $mgl_wrapper.load(mgl_space + ' .mali_oglasi', function() {
            $mgl.animate({'opacity' : 1}, 400);
        });
    });

    e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Comment: I'm glad I'm not the only one who uses `$jqsel` variable name syntax to tag my jQuery objects in the source code.

Comment: **$mgl** is a child of **$mlg_wrapper** (**.mali_oglasi** is child of **.mali_oglasi_wrapper**), and **.kategorija_izbor ul a, .mali_oglas a[role=pretraga]** are children of **.mali_oglasi**

Comment: @Sasha This answer is all you need to know - find the lowest DOM node that is not recreated dynamically and bind the event to that node. Simplifying the selectors would help performance too.